# Cross-classified multi-level model - application to marketing

Tags: logistic, predictive-models, multilevel-analysis, binary-data, lme4-nlme

I am working on predicting whether an individual customer will respond favourably to a marketing campaign (yes/no).
I have data about customers, and their responses to previous campaigns. If possible, I would like to aggregate data across a few campaigns (perhaps 5 or 6 recent ones). This is in part because some campaigns are more successful overall than others.

The campaigns differed in who was contacted: customer 1 may have been approached in campaigns A, B and C and customer 2 in campaigns A and B, for example. What I am interested in, is predicting responses of existing customers 1 and 2, as well as a new customer i, to an entirely new campaign j. I am not interested in predicting responses to the old campaigns A, B and C. The campaigns run sequentially, and in general an old campaign is finished before a new one is started.

My idea to tackle this is via a cross-classified multi-level model. This is because I think otherwise it wouldn't be appropriate to combine data from different campaigns, which do have an overlapping set of customers. I have included below a picture of what I think my data structure is. Does it seem right?

[image: Data structure]

Is there a simpler way of approaching this problem? In the past, we just used data from a single campaign to make predictions about future campaigns, using binary logistic regression. But I think it's a crime not to use the beautiful, rich data available.

If I do go with the multi-level model, what sort of formula should I use in R? Which effects should be fixed, and which random?

Examples of the sort of data I would like to include in the model:

- Customer level: gender.
- Response level: Recency, frequency and monetary value at the time customer was contacted. Recency is the time interval since customer's last purchase, frequency is how often they purchased in say the last year, and monetary value could be the value of their previous purchase.
- Optionally, I also have some campaign level data such as creative budget, but I am not necessarily interested in making inferences at this level, especially since I have data on only 5 or 6 campaigns. I just want to adjust for overall success of the campaign.